# AngularJS pure ng-controller lifecycle hooks

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Suppose a pure **AngualrJS (1.6.x)** controller declared using `ng-controller` directive (in contrary to a component controller).

Does it have lifecycle hooks like `$onInit` or `$onDestroy`?

Comment: You can see the link https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks maybe help you.

Comment: @FerasAlSous I think this does not applies here because the OP is asking for these hooks when the controller is created using the `ng-controller` directive, not using the `.component` approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the section **Scope Life Cycle** in the [scope documentation (v1.6.10)](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/guide/scope) there are not such hooks (*using the [`ng-controller`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngController) approach*).

The scope lifecycle would go like this:

1. **Creation**

The root scope is created during the application bootstrap by the `$injector`. During template linking, some directives create new child scopes.

2. **Watcher registration**

During template linking, directives register watches on the scope. These watches will be used to propagate model values to the DOM.

3. **Model mutation**

For mutations to be properly observed, you should make them only within the `scope.$apply()`. AngularJS APIs do this implicitly, so no extra `$apply` call is needed when doing synchronous work in controllers, or asynchronous work with `$http`, `$timeout` or `$interval` services.

4. **Mutation observation**

At the end of `$apply`, AngularJS performs a `$digest` cycle on the root scope, which then propagates throughout all child scopes. During the `$digest` cycle, all `$watched` expressions or functions are checked for model mutation and if a mutation is detected, the `$watch` listener is called.

5. **Scope destruction**

When child scopes are no longer needed, it is the responsibility of the child scope creator to destroy them via `scope.$destroy()` API. This will stop propagation of `$digest` calls into the child scope and allow for memory used by the child scope models to be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

---

Of course, alternatively, you can always use [`$rootScope.Scope#$on`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) for listening for changes.

Examples:

```
$scope.$on('my-custom-event', function () {
// some code to execute when my-custom-event is fired
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
// some code to execute when the scope is destroyed
});
```